# Mutability in kotlin object

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, synchronized

I'm studying mutability special cases in **Kotlin**.

this is the code I was playing with:

```
var a = 350
val b = a
a = 8
println(b) // 350. ===> should be 8
```

I want to keep the `b` as **val** but at the same time it should be able to take the value of `a` each time `a` variable is modified.

So I tried the object solution but as you see below, **the `x` variable is not accessible.** I suppose this solution is not correct.

```
val object1 = object {
    var x = 350
}
val object2 = object1
object1.x = 8
println(object2.x)
```

Is there a way to synchronize this `x` but without putting the block in a **synchronized annotated funchtion** like below ?

```
@Synchronized
fun someFunction(): Int {

    val object1 = object {
        var x = 350
    }
    val object2 = object1
    object1.x = 8
    println(object2.x)

return object2.x
}
someFunction()
```

Comment: Why do you need to synchronize it? it is safe to set a property concurrently (as long as it doesn't have some logic behind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just define `b` as a property that references `a`:

```kotlin
var a=350
val b: Int
    get()=a
```

Everytime you access `b`, it will redirect that access to `a`.

The following will print `8` and you don't have to use your object solution:

```kotlin
var a=350
val b: Int
    get()=a
fun main() {
    a=8
    println(b)
}
```

Comment: obviously it's more efficient than the Synchronized function solution's. Thank you